# Transform levels of a factor into a new factor in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataframe in the format

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")),
                 V2 = factor(c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes")),
                 V3 = factor(c("No", "Yes", "No", "No")))
```

I want to transform it so that the "Yes" responses in each variable are assigned the variable's name (`V1`, `V2`, and `V3`) and then moved to a new variable, while the "No" responses become `NA`. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
DF_result <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")),
                    V2 = factor(c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes")),
                    V3 = factor(c("No", "Yes", "No", "No")),
                    V_comb = factor(c("V1", NA, "V1", NA, "V2", NA, NA, "V2", NA, "V3", NA, NA)))
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I don't understand the result. Why is row 2 NA when `V3` is "Yes"?

Comment: The second value in `V_comb`, if that's what you mean, is NA because the second value in V1 was "No" -- but ultimately, the order of values in `V_comb` doesn't really matter to me, as long as all the "Yes" answers get transformed into appropriate values with names derived from original variables.

Comment: You haven't defined `DF_result` as intended I think. I'm pretty sure `V_comb` should be 3 columns worth of data, one for each `V1/2/3`.

Comment: `V_comb` does indeed combine the results from the original variables. That's why it has 12 values, and the 3 original variables 4 each.

Comment: the original variables are 36. Look at the DF

Comment: My bad. Sorry. What a dumb mistake--pasted the wrong sample DF from RStudio. I've corrected it.

Comment: `a=DF;a[]=Map(factor,DF,label=rbind.data.frame(NA,names(DF)))` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: To a point. This renames the factor levels, but doesn't combine the "Yes" answers into a new factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cbind(DF,comb=c(mapply(factor,DF,label=rbind.data.frame(NA,names(DF)))))
    V1  V2  V3 comb
1  Yes Yes  No   V1
2   No  No Yes <NA>
3  Yes  No  No   V1
4   No Yes  No <NA>
5  Yes Yes  No   V2
6   No  No Yes <NA>
7  Yes  No  No <NA>
8   No Yes  No   V2
9  Yes Yes  No <NA>
10  No  No Yes   V3
11 Yes  No  No <NA>
12  No Yes  No <NA>
```

Comment: Actually, after trying all the solutions on my actual dataset, I've found this to work best, so I'm changing the accepted answer to this.

Answer (score 3):

Largely a variation on @Moody_Mudskipper's answer, but you can do:

```
cbind(DF, V_comb=c(ifelse(DF=="Yes", names(DF)[col(DF)], NA)))

#    V1  V2  V3 V_comb
#1  Yes Yes  No     V1
#2   No  No Yes   <NA>
#3  Yes  No  No     V1
#4   No Yes  No   <NA>
#5  Yes Yes  No     V2
#6   No  No Yes   <NA>
#7  Yes  No  No   <NA>
#8   No Yes  No     V2
#9  Yes Yes  No   <NA>
#10  No  No Yes     V3
#11 Yes  No  No   <NA>
#12  No Yes  No   <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly for my purposes, since I only really care about `V_comb`, but it's a rather unfortunate side effect to have the original variables lengthened.

Comment: @KaC - that's a limitation of a data.frame - it has to be rectangular. If you just want the new factor, just use the `c(ifelse(DF=="Yes", names(DF)[col(DF)], NA))` part.

Comment: Here is another version `cbind(DF, V_comb = names(DF)[col(DF)* NA^(DF != "Yes")])` (may be bit concise) ;)

Answer (score 2):

In base `R`

```
DF2 <- data.frame(DF,V_comb= c(as.matrix(DF)))
DF2$V_comb <- ifelse(DF2$V_comb == "Yes", rep(names(DF),each=nrow(DF)),NA)
DF2
#     V1  V2  V3 V_comb
# 1  Yes Yes  No     V1
# 2   No  No Yes   <NA>
# 3  Yes  No  No     V1
# 4   No Yes  No   <NA>
# 5  Yes Yes  No     V2
# 6   No  No Yes   <NA>
# 7  Yes  No  No   <NA>
# 8   No Yes  No     V2
# 9  Yes Yes  No   <NA>
# 10  No  No Yes     V3
# 11 Yes  No  No   <NA>
# 12  No Yes  No   <NA>
```